# How to resolve DNS using IPtables rule , if the resolving IP keeps changing frequently

Tags: dns, ip, iptables

We have **IPtables** rule enabled. We have allowed some specific DNS for eg. `test.example.com`, but the resolving IP for `test.example.com` keeps changing frequently, so getting **connection timed out** till we flush and re-enable iptables rule. What is the solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

By definition if you use names, they are resolved at the moment you create the filtering rules. So if the resolution changes later you need to recreate the rules. You could have a monitoring script that checks each 5 minutes or something if the DNS resolution changed, and if so, reload the rules.

The other option is to find once for all all the IP addresses your name could resolve to, and put this as list. See the `ipset` feature at http://ipset.netfilter.org/ and/or make sure to create a specific ipfilter separate chain for easy maintenance.